# DSolve PDE with boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations

Analytically solve following PDE:
$$u_{tt}+2u_{xt}+u_{xx}=u_t-u_x, \ u(x,x)=e^{-4x^2}$$
I can solve it by hand 
$$u(x,t)=\frac{e^{-\frac{(x+t)^2}{1+8(t-x)}}}{\sqrt{1+8(t-x)}}$$
But this boundary condition can't be recognized by my mathematica:

```
  pde = D[u[x, t], t, t] + 2 D[u[x, t], x, t] + D[u[x, t], x, x]
  - D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0;
  soln = DSolve[{pde, u[x, x] == E^(-4 x^2)}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

They said it can't recognize this boundary condition.

Comment: In general `hand` is better than CAS.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I hope mathematica can do these kind of thing. I don't want to cost my time to do these kinds of computation in my research.

Comment: Mathematica can't solve this. `Dsolve` is weak, it can solve only most popular and simple equations.Try `Maple`  `:)`

Answer (score 1):

We don't normally allow mixed time/space BCs since they are not, in general, well posed, and it is better to return no answer than the wrong answer. There is a further complication that it is trying to figure out which equations are differential equations and which are BCs (a cost of allowing you to freely specify as many of each as you want, in any order), and it's being confused here by seeing $u(x,x)$.  I will file a suggestion about this, but it is not so easy to fix.